# Red mute icon under time causes no sound in Kodi

Tags: audio, android, kodi

I have just gotten a small red mute icon under the time in top right corner: A loud speaker followed by X.

Sound is now gone: Both from video and from the UI. Sound works fine in Android, so this is not a hardware issue.

It is also not the normal mute of sound (i.e. turning down the sound level to 0).

It appeared while I selected a new title (sound was fine until then), so I may have pressed something on the remote.

Rebooting does not help.

I have also tried this: http://kod1help.com/red-mute-icon-audio-fix-kodi-devices-no-sound with no luck.

How do I enable sound in Kodi again?

Kodi: 17.4 on Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected this is very simple to solve: Press + or - on the *keyboard* (not the remote control).

Comment: Thanks a ton for this; on my Android, I found no way to raise a virtual keybooard, and connecting with adb to the device and issuing `adb shell input keyevent 81` (see https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28045/is-there-any-way-to-manually-bring-up-the-keyboard) helped